# Magento 2.3.1 - Checkout dropdown cart image aspect ratio is incorrect

Tags: checkout, magento2.3, product-images

Adding a product where it's image is wide (landscape), gets squeezed into a portrait sized place holder.

As below.

[image]

How can I get the image to fit into the cart image placeholder and maintain its aspect ratio?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your `mini_cart_product_thumbnail` image dimensions.

> YOUR_MAGENTO_THEME_DIRECTORY > etc > view.xml

```
<media>
    <images module="Magento_Catalog">        
        <image id="mini_cart_product_thumbnail" type="thumbnail">
            <width>75</width>
            <height>75</height>
        </image>
     </images>
</media>
```

Comment: This doesn't fix the issue of adjusting the aspect ratio to fit in image placeholder or making the image place holder dimensions dynamic to fit the images aspect ratio.